Print all records in a single RollSheet Paper
I want to create an rtf to print by BI Publisher on a RollSheet Paper .
I've set a repeating group that creates several records on print paper but I want to have all of them in a single paper (I mean it won't print some of them on the next page ,all of them should be printed in a single paper )
How can I set unlimited height for my paper for this purpose ?
I couldn't set unlimited height in page setup of word

Can you be more specific on what this rollsheet of paper is? Or are you trying to keep 1 row together so if it does print it is not split up across two pages?

File types cannot be unlimited resources otherwise they would exceed a disk or memory.
Likewise Printers and their formats have limits. For example a PDF or its printer cannot normally print beyond 200 inches.
So here I set one page long to 3000 mm as many paper rolls come in 3 metre lengths.
Thus WordPad can print RTF multiple pages 300 cm long no problem (118 inches is well inside the 200" limit). IF I have such a printer like GhostScript (PostScript).

So the limitations in printing are decided by programming the print driver directly. To program printers in Windows is not that simple, as there are many GUI controls for forms and your best bet are VBScripts or PrintUI.exe / dll.
Once set then WordPad can command line print any RTF to the designated printer, so I can print up to the media limit as pre-set before print.
write /pt C:\Users\lez\Downloads\demo\lorum.rtf "Microsoft Print To PDF"
or
write /pt C:\Users\lez\Downloads\demo\lorum.rtf "GhostScript PDF"
It is the programming before printing, determines page length. So here rotated to show the difference. Microsoft is A4 length whereas GhostScript has been set to 200 inches.

